# Count Estimate on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I was having troubles with a count query, it was too slow. Then i found an article talking about the Count Estimate on PostgreSQL. It uses the function below to estimate the amount of rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.count_estimate(query text)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec   record;
    ROWS  INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query LOOP
        ROWS := SUBSTRING(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
        EXIT WHEN ROWS IS NOT NULL;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN ROWS;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.count_estimate(text)
```

And i use it like this:

```
SELECT count_estimate('SELECT * FROM table');
```

The query I pass to the function accepts conditions (=, >, <, LIKE, SIMILAR TO ...), but when I try to use this specific conditional `~` it returns me a wrong count.

Is there anyway to adapt this function to make it works with `~` in where clause?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "returns a wrong count"? Are you aware that the execution plan returns an **estimate**? The optimizer does not have enough information to properly _estimate_ the number of matches for regular expression. There is no way you will get anywhere near reality with a regex match in the execution plan.

Comment: I know that it returns an estimate, but in this case it's returning me just 3 rows in a real count of 800 rows. Like you said when I use regex I don't get near reality. :(

Comment: There is nothing you can do about that. Postgres doesn't store enough statistics to be able to give you a better estimate.

Comment: that function is explained in this article https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate where it says that the result is an estimate, not the real count.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html

the function you use just runs `EXPLAIN` and parses the output to show the expected number of rows. The only way to "adapt" the function for showing better results here - is adding `ANALYZE` after the `EXPLAIN` to get "actual" rows. But of course it will cost you the actual execution of the query you pass as argument, so it makes no sense to estimate the count before running the actual query, if you estimate after actually running it.